# Waiting for parallel RX subscribers to complete

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

I'm looking for the best method to wait for async tasks to finish in rx-java.

As a common example say there is a function which gets a list of id's from a local store and then queries a remote system for those Id's, the remote system results are then consolidated into a single report and returned to the caller of the function. As the call to the remote system is slow we want them to be done in asynchronously and I only want to return once all of the calls have returned and their results have been processed.

The only reliable way I have found to do this is to poll the subscription to check it is unsubscribed yet. But I'm thinking doesn't seem to be the 'RX' way to do things!

As an example I've taken the example from http://howrobotswork.wordpress.com/2013/10/28/using-rxjava-in-android/ and amended it slightly to make it non-android and to show what I mean. I have to have the following code at the of the main() method to stop it exiting immediately.

```
while (!subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

The full code for the example is listed below (it is dependent on http://square.github.io/retrofit/ if your trying to compile it)

```
package org.examples;

import retrofit.RestAdapter;
import retrofit.http.GET;
import retrofit.http.Query;
import rx.Observable;
import rx.Subscriber;
import rx.Subscription;
import rx.functions.Action0;
import rx.functions.Action1;
import rx.functions.Func1;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class AsyncExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final Subscription subscription = Observable.from("London", "Paris", "Berlin")
                .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<WeatherData>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<WeatherData> call(String s) {
                        return ApiManager.getWeatherData(s);
                    }
                })
                .subscribe(
                        new Action1<WeatherData>() {
                            @Override
                            public void call(WeatherData weatherData) {
                                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - " + weatherData.name + ", " + weatherData.base);
                            }
                        },
                        new Action1<Throwable>() {
                            @Override
                            public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - ERROR: " + throwable.getMessage());
                            }
                        },
                        new Action0() {
                            @Override
                            public void call() {
                                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - COMPLETED");
                            }
                        }
                );

        // Have to poll subscription to check if its finished - is this the only way to do it?
        while (!subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }
}

class ApiManager {

    private interface ApiManagerService {
        @GET("/weather")
        WeatherData getWeather(@Query("q") String place, @Query("units") String units);
    }

    private static final RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5")
            .build();
    private static final ApiManagerService apiManager = restAdapter.create(ApiManagerService.class);

    public static Observable<WeatherData> getWeatherData(final String city) {
        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<WeatherData>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super WeatherData> subscriber) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " - Getting " + city);
                    subscriber.onNext(apiManager.getWeather(city, "metric"));
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    subscriber.onError(e);
                }
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }
}
```

Comment: It feels like you're going at this in reverse.  If you're looking at waiting for everything to finish why would you use the `Schedulers.io`?  If you don't use any schedulers then rx-java is by default synchronous.  Everything would complete synchronously and then you would return.  I know you mentioned you wanted to do this asynchronously but then you go against your own desire by wanting to wait for it to complete.

Comment: The reason for `Schedulers.io` is that I want each remote system call to be in a separate thread hence I get parallelism and the overall function is faster.

Answer (score 5):

If you are asking how to turn an asynchronous Observable into a synchronous one you can use .toBlocking() and then use .last() to wait for the Observable to complete.. For example, the following will not continue until the timer completes even though the timer executes on the computation thread.

```java
try {
    Observable
            .timer(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .toBlocking()
            .last();    // Wait for observable to complete. Last item discarded.
} catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    // No items or error.
}
```

You probably shouldn't use this method unless absolutely necessary. Normally, application termination would be controlled by some other event (key press, close menu item click, etc.) Your network request Observables would complete asynchronously and you would take action in the onNext(), onCompleted() and onError() calls to update the UI or display an error.

Also, the beauty of Retrofit is that it has built in support for RxJava and will execute network requests in the background. To use that support declare you interface as returning an Observable.

```java
interface ApiManagerService {
    @GET("/weather")
    Observable<WeatherData> getWeather(@Query("q") String place, @Query("units") String units);
}
```

Which allows you to simplify your getWeatherData() method to this:

```java
public static Observable<WeatherData> getWeatherData(final String city) {
    return apiManager.getWeather(city, "metric");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For the purpose of synchronous waiting for asynchronous observаble I wrote a simple function:

```
public static <T> void runSynchronously(Observable<T> observable) {
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final AtomicReference<Throwable> exception = new AtomicReference<>();

    observable.subscribe(new Subscriber<T>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            latch.countDown();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            exception.set(e);
            latch.countDown();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(T o) {
        }
    });

    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    if (exception.get() != null) {
        throw Exceptions.propagate(exception.get());
    }
}
```

You can use it this way:

```
    Observer<String> sideEffects = new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            System.out.println("onCompleted");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("onError: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(String s) {
            System.out.println("onNext: " + s);
        }
    };

    runSynchronously(
            Observable.just("London", "Paris", "Berlin")
                    .doOnEach(sideEffects)
    );
```

Comment: @LangustenGustel Can you explain why? Just writing that it's not good is not very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases it's better not to block a method. Try to be as non-blocking as possible. If you need to do something after an Observable has completed simply invoke your logic from the `onCompleted` callback, or use the [`doOnCompleted`](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Observable-Utility-Operators#dooncompleted) operator.

If you really, really need to block then you can use the [`Blocking Observable Operators`](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Blocking-Observable-Operators).
Most of these operators block until the Observable completes.

However, stopping your main method from exiting prematurely can be achieved by a simple `System.in.read()` at the end.